# Cassandra Insert/Delete Issue

Tags: cassandra

I have 3 nodes where `cassandra 3.0.9` is installed where node 1 & 2 are in same datacenter while node 3 is different data center. In this Topology node 1 and 3 are seed nodes.

Details of `cassandra.yaml` file:

```
ListenAddress : publicIP
rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
broadcast_rpc_address: publicIP
seeds : PulicIP of node1 and node3
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
```

when I insert or delete data from any of the node that is not getting reflacted on other nodes or it may reflect on one node not rest all nodes.

inserting data into table like below :

```
INSERT INTO test.country (name, code, currency, currencycode) VALUES ('India', 'IND', 'Rupee rupee', 'Rs');
```

This insertion of data has been done using connecting to one node via cqlsh.

Comment: what is your replication factor for the keyspace?

Comment: replication factor is 3

Answer (score 2):

Replace your `rpc_address:` from `0.0.0.0` to each nodes `public_ip`. Then restart `cassandra` on each node. Then try to insert data again and `SELECT` from another node to test.